# get calendarrules by servicenameid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 (on premise) I need to delete Service Restrictions, Associated with a specific service. It looks like they are stored in "calendarrules", but when i try to find some info in my collection of calendarrules, I do not see any attributes similar to "ServiceNameId".
I found the information that this can be done simply by changing the entries of the calendar rule and updating the original calendar, so I try to do it as follows, but can't see attributes referring me to services.

I get the collection as follows:

```
SystemUser user = service.Retrieve(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, UserId, new ColumnSet("calendarid")).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
            Calendar userCalendar = service.Retrieve(Calendar.EntityLogicalName, user.CalendarId.Id, new ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<Calendar>();

            EntityCollection entityCollection = (EntityCollection)userCalendar.Attributes["calendarrules"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it can be found on innercalendars and updated by this way:

```
SystemUser user = service.Retrieve(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, serviceappointment.OwnerId.Id, new ColumnSet("calendarid")).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                    Calendar userCalendar = service.Retrieve(Calendar.EntityLogicalName, user.CalendarId.Id, new ColumnSet(true)).ToEntity<Calendar>();

                    EntityCollection entityCollection = (EntityCollection)userCalendar.Attributes["calendarrules"];
                    foreach (Entity ent in entityCollection.Entities)
                    {
                        int num = 0;
                        Entity newEntity = service.Retrieve("calendar", ((EntityReference)ent.Attributes["innercalendarid"]).Id, new ColumnSet(true));

                        EntityCollection calendarRules = (EntityCollection)newEntity.Attributes["calendarrules"];

                        List<int> list = new List<int>();

                        foreach (CalendarRule cr in calendarRules.Entities)
                        {
                            if (cr.ServiceId != null)
                            {
                                list.Add(num);
                            }
                            num++;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                        {
                            calendarRules.Entities.Remove(calendarRules.Entities[list[i]]);
                        }
                        newEntity.Attributes["calendarrules"] = calendarRules;
                        service.Update(newEntity);

                    }
```

Perhaps there is a simpler way, but for now this is enough